# Shared-Memory System in Operating System Concept

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, producer-consumer, circular-buffer

I'm studying about the Operating System in the book Operating System Concept 8th Edition.

In the chapter about the process, there's one thing about the shared-memory system that i don't understand.

The following variables reside in a region of memory shared by the producer and the consumer processes:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
typedef struct{
...
}iten;
item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int i = 0;
int out = 0;
```

The shared buffer is implemented as a circular array with 2 logical pointers, in and out. The variable in points to the next free position in the buffer, out points to the first full position in the buffer.

The producer process:

```
item nextProceduced
while(true){
   /*produce an intem in nextProduced*/
   while(((in+1)%BUFFER_SIZE) == out)
       ;//do nothing
   buffer[in] = nextProceduced;
   in = (in+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
```

}

The consumer process:

```
   item nextConsume
   while(true){
        /*produce an intem in nextProduced*/
        while(in == out)
            ;//do nothing
        nextComsumed = buffer[out]
        out = (out+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
   }
```

It says:"The buffer is empty when in == out, the buffer is full when ((i+1)%BUFFER_SiZE) == out ,**This scheme allows at most BUFFER_SIZE-1 items in the buffer at the same time".**

For the statement :"the buffer is full when ((i+1)%BUFFER_SiZE) == out", i don't really under stand this.

For example, if the buffer is full then "in" will point to the buffer[9] element, and "out" will point to buffer[8] element, how can the buffer is full when ((i+1)%BUFFER_SiZE) == out?

Comment: This is just common technique to detect empty vs. full. How would you distinguish the two having in==out? Never make the queue completely full, leave one slot empty and you are done.

Comment: Firda is right. Maybe it makes more sense if you consider that it's a circular buffer, so the value of the first index is equivalent to every other one and it's only the second element's relation that makes a difference. If you now take pen&paper, draw the input index at position 4 and draw the queue size for every output index, you will find the answer. Note that you can also use a counter, so that you don't waste one queue slot. Further, you don't mention synchronization, but accessing this structure from multiple processes without mutex will cause race conditions.

Comment: For more on circular buffer, you can read it up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Full_.2F_Empty_Buffer_Distinction

Comment: Hi Ulrich, i don't understand , if "in" stop at 4 and the "out" will stop at 3, so what's next?

Comment: An alternative is to have a count of the number of items in the queue and/or a semaphore used as a synchronous form of count.